# Translate newline to comma

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

I have a text file having a list of around 150 to 200 file names

```
abc.txt
pqr.txt
xyz.txt
...
...
```

I need a string of comma separated files.
Each string should have not more than 20 files. So the echo will look something like this...

```
$string1="abc.txt,pqr.txt,xyz.txt..."
$string2="abc1.txt,pqr1.txt,xyz1.txt..."
...
```

The number of strings will be different depending upon the number of lines in the file. I have written something like this...

```
#!/bin/sh
delim=','
for gsfile in `cat filelist.txt`
do
filelist=$filelist$delim$gsfile
echo $filelist
done
```

Translate command is working as expected, but how do I restrict each string to 20 filenames?

```
cat filelist.txt | tr '\n' ','
```

Comment: you can have one variables array, and looping trough your list check if % 20 == 0, then assign to next variable from your variable array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `xargs`:

```
$ seq 1 50 | xargs -n20 | tr ' ' ,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
seq 41 | paste -sd ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n' 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
41
```

or GNU sed:

```
seq 41 | sed ':a;$bb;N;s/\n/&/19;Ta;:b;y/\n/,/'
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
41
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `sed`:

Add like *Igor Chubin* 50 numbers to `infile`:

```
seq 1 50 >infile
```

Content of `script.sed`:

```
:b
## While not last line...
$! {
    ## Check if line has 19 newlines. Try substituting the line with itself and
    ## check if it succeed, then append next line and do it again in a loop.
    s/\(\n[^n]*\)\{19\}/&/
    ta  
    N   
    bb  
}

## There are 20 lines in the buffer or found end of file, so substitute all '\n' 
## with commas and print.
:a
s/\n/,/g
p
```

Run it like:

```
sed -nf script.sed infile
```

With following output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag in sed's `s` command to replace every 20th comma with a newline:

```
 < filelist.txt tr '\n' , | sed ':a; s/,/\n/20; P; D; ta'; echo
```